# CentOS booting into kernel panic after Glibc update

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, glibc

I foolishly tried to update Glibc to a newer version, got segfaults and rebooted, only to face this error:

[image]

It's a VM running CentOS 6.2 64bit on Kernel PV 64bit (4.4.27-x86_64-jb1) I only have remote access to.

I have the option do boot into a different kernel, could I simply do that to access a webserver and mysql db that is installed on the same system it doesn't want to boot into?

I've read elsewhere that I could simply re-install the correct Glibc libs for the distribution, however I can't since I can't boot into it in the first place.

Comment: You could try the kernel parameter `init=/bin/bash`, but if `init` does not find its library, `bash` probably won't either.

Answer (score 1):

> I foolishly tried to update Glibc

Yes, incorrect upgrade of GLIBC is an easy way to render your system unbootable.

> I have the option do boot into a different kernel

The different kernel will have exact same problem. Your problem is not with the kernel, it's that `/sbin/init`, which is the very first *user space* process the kernel creates, can't run.

Recovery is sill *possible*, but may be quite complicated (and may or may not be worth the effort, depending on how much data you have in the MySQL database).

You'll need to get access to the root file system you are booting into, mount it into some other VM as a *non*-root file system, repair it (remove your botched installed GLIBC parts and re-install the original package), and unmount it. After that you'll be able to boot your original VM.

The exact details of what you need to do depend on which VM you are actually using and how you've configured its disks.