# Installing glibc-2.29 from source in kali linux

Tags: glibc

I need a debug version of glibc.I have some doubts regarding the installation of glibc-2.29 from source in kali linux.Based on the post https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Glibc-Install-HOWTO/,

> To install glibc you need a system with nothing running on it, since many processes (for example sendmail) always try to use the library and therefore block the files from being replaced. Therefore we need a "naked" system, running nothing except the things we absolutely need. You can achieve this by passing the boot option
>   init=/bin/bash to your kernel.

it says that we need to install the glibc in a single usermode environment.In another post https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Glibc2-HOWTO-5.html 
single usermode is not required for installation but backing up the old libraries.I dont know which one to follow.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I found that we can use glibc without installing but building from source by adding '-g' flag in ./configure and setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH varible as follows after building

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/the/build_directory gdb -q application
```

**Note:** this solution only works when the system GLIBC and the built-from-source GLIBC exactly match, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

Answer (score 0):

> I need a debug version of glibc.

Most distributions *supply* ready-made libc6-dbg packages that match your installed GLIBC. This is the best approach unless you are a GLIBC developer (or plan to become one).

> I have some doubts regarding the installation of glibc-2.29 from source in kali linux.

Installing / replacing system libc is almost guaranteed to render your system unbootable if there are any mistakes. Recent [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42224012/50617).

Before you begin, make sure you either know how to recover from such a mistake (have a rescue disk ready and know how to use it), or you have nothing of value on the system and can re-image it from installation media in the likely case that you do make a mistake.

The document you referenced talks about upgrading from libc5 to libc6. It was last updated on 22 June 1998, and is more than 20 years old. I suggest you find some more recent sources. Current documentation does [suggest](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Running-make-install.html#Running-make-install) doing `make install` while in single-user mode.

Comment: @John You appear to replace a "simple" sysadmin  procedure with a "very complicated" one instead. If you can't solve the simple problem, you should generally not attempt the complicated one. Advice: ask a separate question along the lines of "I have these packages installed, but GDB is giving me this warning and refuses to use the debug package. How can I fix that?"